# Should I use public $var or should I use __construct()?

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP OOP, and I think `public $var` and `__construct()` are exactly the same.
What's the difference? Which one should I use?

Comment: apple and oranges here: $var is an property - a variable; __construct() is a method - a function that does something.

Comment: Perhaps explain why you think that they are "the same"?

Comment: Because I use __construct($var){$this->var=$var} to make a variable a property like public $var does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are *completely* different things: one declares a class property, and the other is the name of the class constructor.

There is no such thing as "one or the other" here.

I suggest re-reading all about [classes and objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) in your PHP book, or the manual.

Answer (score 0):

`public $var` is **not** a constructor, which `__construct()` is. I hope you meant something else.

As stated in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php), there's two kinds of constructors:

```
class Bar {
    public function Bar() {
        // "old" style constructor
    }
}

class Foo {
   function __construct() {
       // new style constructor
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public $var;
```

Declares a variable that will be accessible to the outside world.

```
function __construct () { /* Do stuff */ }
```

Defines the "magic" constructor method. This method will be invoked when a new instance is created (i.e. when you create a `new` object). This method is what accepts and handles any arguments that are passed when creating a new object.

The key difference is that one defined a variable (property) and one defines a function (method).